# Argoproj: Execute command after -Outputs- are completed in Argo workflow

Tags: kubernetes, argo-workflows, argoproj

I have an Argo workflow YAML file responsible for running some templates on the cloud.

```
spec:
  entrypoint: templateA
  onExit: templateB

  templates:
    - name: templateA
     <templateA YAML specs here>

    - name: templateB

      container:
        image: <SOME IMAGE>
        command: [sh, -c]
        args: ["echo Hello World"]

      outputs:
        artifacts:
          <CODE TO COPY FROM LOCAL TO S3>
```

I want to run a command when the transfer is completed or error has occurred. For eg: I want to record the timestamp and print it when the output artifacts transfer is completed.

What is the correct mechanism for me to achieve this?